# notepad++ how to run curl requests?

Tags: curl, notepad++, nppexec

I was wondering if there is any way i could run curl in notepad++

I came across http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/cross-browser-css-in-seconds-with-prefixr/ where it shows how to run `http://prefixr.com/` in a terminal

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to get Prefixr working with NppExec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the NppExec plugin which embeds a Command Prompt into notepad++ then run anything you need from the command line.

To get it, go to **Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager** and find "NppExec"

Comment: As an aside it should be installed by default in new Notepad++ installations.

Answer (score 1):

Use NppExec plugin within Notepad++ to create a script to invoke CURL. I use curl to submit SQL for formatting using following NppExec script.

```
// enable $(OUTPUT) variable
NPE_CONSOLE v+
// this temporary file name will be used 
set TEMP_FILE = $(SYS.TEMP)\npp_sel.txt 
// save current selection as ANSI text file 
SEL_SAVETO $(TEMP_FILE) :a 
// POST selection to sql format the selection
curl -s --data-urlencode data@"$(TEMP_FILE)"  -d keyword_case=upper -d reindent=true -d n_indents=2 -d format=text "http://sqlformat.appspot.com/format"
// open new editor pane
NPP_SENDMSG WM_COMMAND IDM_FILE_NEW
// replace the selected text: cmd's output
SEL_SETTEXT $(OUTPUT)
// finally, disable $(OUTPUT) variable
NPE_CONSOLE v-
```